# How to copy from one vim window to another MacOS

Tags: vim, terminal, copy

How can i copy from one vim process to another (for example with shortcut "yy") on MacOS El Capitan 10.11.5 ?
I'm find different solutions but mostly of them not works or work in vim with GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- when you work multiple files with vim, try using same vim process(you meant "vim window"), with different buffers, or tabs, instead of multiple vim processes
- Since you have started two (or more) vim processes, the vim internal `y` `p` won't work cross the processes. But if your vim was compiled with clipboard feature, you can in one vim do `"+Y` then in another vim `"+p` , this uses your system clipboard to copy & paste.